# apps installed from ubuntu software don't launch

Tags: 16.04, software-center, snap

The applications I install using the ubuntu software center don't launch. However if I install the same application from terminal it works fine.

I by mistake ran the command `sudo rm -rf snap` from the root directory.

I already tried reinstalling Ubuntu Software. I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version.

Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm really unsure what the effect of the command that you ran would have, but I suspect it's not all good.  You could try `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't help